# Proving addition is associative in $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: proof-writing, field-theory

I have to prove that $\mathbb{R}$ is a field. 
One of the properties for $\mathbb{R}$ to be a field is that addition in $\mathbb{R}$ is associative. I wanted to use this property as an example for the other ones.

My question is, how can I show something so intuitive? Can I say that it is simply assumed that addition in $\mathbb{R}$ is associative?
Or should I use $a+(b+c)=(a+b)+c$ for $a,b,c \in \mathbb{R}$ in some way?

I am sorry for the silly question, it has been a while since I proved something.
Thank you.

Comment: What is $R{}{}$?

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown The real numbers, I'll try to change the symbol now.

Comment: That depends on what you already know about the real numbers and what definitions you are working with.  To prove it from first principles you might have to go so far as to prove it for the natural numbers first, then proving it for the integers using that it is true for naturals, and then proving it for rationals using that it is true for integers, and then proving it for cauchy sequences of rationals thereby proving it for reals.

Comment: Are you defining $\mathbb{R}$ via Dedekind cuts or equivalence classes of Cauchy sequences?

Comment: All I am given in the problem is to "prove that R and Q with the standard addition and multiplication are fields". And we were just given the definition of a field. I am finding it very weird, I took an abstract algebra class in the past and remember that a lot had to be learned before fields @MikeHaskel

Comment: That's not enough context. Usually $\Bbb R$ is presented *with* the field axioms.

Comment: @JMoravitz Thank you, I hadn't seen that post. So I'm guessing that I can just say that this property is assumed for the real numbers?

Comment: Again, that depends on your audience and what is actually expected of you.  It is a good exercise to go through the full process of defining the real numbers and proving all of their properties at least once.  If you are expected to be perfectly rigorous, you absolutely cannot just say the property is assumed.  If you are expected to do this as just one step among many in a homework assignment that shouldn't cover more than a quarter of a page, then go ahead and skip the step saying "*it is well known that...*"